# Scraping website with DOM and XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am trying to get a list of links from a webpage with PHP. This is what I've tried:

```
$webpage = file_get_contents('http://cl1.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php');

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($webpage);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('aside/ul/li/ul/li/a');//returns nothing

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
}
```

The code works until it has to perform the query, when it returns an empty object.

I've also tried this to solve the aforementioned problem:

```
$dom->getElementsByTagName('aside')->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(1)->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes;
```

I know that this last code doesn't return all the elements, but, even so, it doesn't work.

EDIT:

This is part of the html:

```
<aside class='layout-menu'>

    <ul class='parent-menu-list'>
                    <li>
            <a href="ref.funchand.php">Function handling Functions</a>

                                <ul class='child-menu-list'>


                    <li class="current">
                        <a href="function.call-user-func-array.php" title="call_&#8203;user_&#8203;func_&#8203;array">call_&#8203;user_&#8203;func_&#8203;array</a>
                    </li>
```

Comment: is that the proper xpath query?  Without beinf familiar with the HTML structure, it is hard to say whether your query should even match any nodes. I know for instance that the `aside/ul/li/ul/li/a` would never work as you are not starting from root node but since you are using entire document (not document fragement) the relative declaration would be relative to root.

Comment: I used the complete path (/html/body/div/aside/ul/li/ul/li/a) and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how your query would match.  You are using a relative query on the entire document, so you would in essence be doing a relative query from the document root.

Try to either specify your query from root node like:

```
// instantiate DOMXPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// use full path hierarchy in query
$links = $xpath->query('/html/body/.../aside/ul/li/ul/li/a');
```

Or pass `aside` node context to xpath for use with relative query.

```
// get DOMNode object for aside element
$aside_tag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('aside')->item(0);
// instantiate DOMXPath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// pass DOMNode context to DOMXPath::query()
$links = $xpath->query('ul/li/ul/li/a', $aside_tag);
```

Comment: @Frederico  I added better example to my answer on how you can do `DOMXPath::query()` in relative fashion based on `aside` node context.